# How to generate my python output as a HTML

Tags: python, html, dominate, yattag

```
import dominate
from dominate.tags import *
doc = dominate.document(title='Cell Value report')
with doc:
    with div():
        attr(cls='body')
        h2('Values Missing in the files.....')
    with div(id='header').add(ol()):
        for i in unique_file:
            li(i.title())
```

I tried this, to generate my python output in a HTML. 
The HTML part is working fine if I hardcode the path in the `os.listdir`
But it shows error if I use path as input.

```py
search_path = input("Enter directory path to search: ")#directory path
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):
```

***This is the Error
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not input_***

I even tried a library **yattag**
I have a `List[]` in python, which I have to loop and  print as a list in HTML.
I tried in **yattag** and I can't achieve, I'm not sure what I did wrong.
Is there any other libraries I should use to achieve my output.
Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Looks like your wildcard import (`from dominate.tags import *`) shadowed the builtin `input` function (there's an "input" tag in HTML...). This is why you should __never__ use wildcard imports, whatever your lib's documentation says.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is there any other way i should look for.

Comment: "is there any other way i should look for" => replace `from dominator.tags import *` with `from dominator import tags`, then replace all your calls to `div()`, `h2()`, `li()` etc by (resp.)  `tags.div()`, `tags.h2()` etc.

Comment: OR explicitely import the tags you want to use (`from dominator.tags import div, li, h2`, etc), but the first solution avoids having to edit your imports each time you want to use another tag, and makes the code clearer (you don't have to check the imports to know where `div`, `li` or whatever comes from) and more robust (you don't have such name clashes...).

Comment: NB: remember that (in real life at least) you read code much more often than you write it, so typing a few more characters once is really worth the effort on the long term ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i tried the first one and its working.Thank you so much :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you now get the point about avoiding wildcard imports ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yeah i learnt about the wildcard imports and  i will be following this form now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of the wildcard imports.`from dominate.tags import *`. `dominate.tags` defines an `input` class that shadowed the builtin `input()` function.

This code works fine without the error.

```
from dominate import tags
with doc:
    with tags.div():
        tags.attr(cls='body')
        tags.h2('Values Missing in the files.....')
    with tags.div(id='header').add(tags.ol()):
        for i in unique_file:
            tags.li(i.title())
```